# Trying to create a directory with two lines with file.path function due to being long but getting an odd forward slash

Tags: r, directory

```
directory<-file.path(r"(C:\File\Folder1\Folder2)",
                 r"(Source\)")
```

I was told told that this script should work but what happens is that the outcome looks like this

```
C:\\File\\Folder1\\Folder2\\/Source\\
```

I don't understand why am i getting that forward slash right before the last folder in the output.

```
C:\\File\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Source\\
```

Comment: It is just for escape.  Check with `cat` i.e. `cat(directory)
C:\File\Folder1\Folder2/Source\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a single character

```
nchar(r"(\)")
[1] 1
```

The other character escape can be checked with `cat`

```
> cat(r"(\)")
\

> cat(directory)
C:\File\Folder1\Folder2/Source\
```

---

The `fsep` can be changed in `file.path`

```
directory <- file.path(r"(C:\File\Folder1\Folder2)",
                  r"(Source)", fsep = "\\")
> cat(directory)
C:\File\Folder1\Folder2\Source
```

Comment: when i run `cat(directory)` I still get C:\\File\\Folder1\\Folder2\\/Source

Comment: @user35131 what is the `nchar` showing for you in my first code block

Comment: 1 is showing up for me.

Comment: @user35131 yes, it is just the printing escape and nothing to worry about

Comment: I'm trying to read from the `file.path` but because of the forward slash `/` it says the folder doesnt exist.

Comment: @user35131 Can you check the path from the directly by copying the copy unix path and see what you get.  If it is backward slash you need to construct it like that

Comment: C:\File\Folder1\Folder2\Source

Comment: @user35131 in your code there is `/` before the Source created by the `file.path`

Comment: My output is C:\\File\\Folder1\\Folder2\\/Source

Comment: @user35131 try the change in `fsep` in my post and check if it works

Comment: My `read_excel` script was written slightly wrong and so I thought the path doesn't exist, but the `/` i see doesn't matter as you said.

Comment: @user35131 it is just that `file.path` by default uses `/` as fsep and thus it causes the issue